# How can I get YOLOv7 to train on all images in my dataset, instead of just one?

Tags: python, dataset, artificial-intelligence, yolo, yolov7

I have a question concerning Training the dataset in yolov7; it is only reading 1 image and the dataset contains more than 20 images training not done
!python train.py --device 0 --batch-size 16 --epochs 100 --img 640 640 --data data/custom_data.yaml --hyp data/hyp.scratch.custom.yaml --cfg cfg/training/yolov7_custom.yaml --name yolov7_custom --weights yolov7.pt
I am using this command the epoch works but is only reading 1 image
I am using my own dataset [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq8rm.png)
can someone help?thanks

i expected to read all the images from my dataset and not only one
at the end when writing this command to see the changes ;  i gave it an image in order to tell me the name of the character but instead it returns the same image only
!python detect.py --weights /content/gdrive/MyDrive/VisionIsAllYouNeed/yolov7/runs/train/yolov7_custom2/weights/best.pt --conf 0.4 --img-size 640 --source 1.jpeg --no-trace